# Trying to get Date/Time from earlier record which meets certain criteria compared to current record, in order to calculate the time difference

Tags: ms-access

This is obviously mocked up data. But what I want to find out is, for each record where *Activity* is Trash, how much time elapsed since the food was served.

Basically for each Trash record, I find the "serve" for that record by matching *Userid*, *Customer*, and *Food*, and *Activity*=Serve and then finding the Max *DateTime* for that match which is less than the *DateTime* of the current record.

It seems like that convoluted logic will work. And it is sort of working, but something is going wrong where I don't properly identify the serve record.

Any help is appreciated!

The query I am trying:

```
SELECT Format((SELECT S.DateTime-Max(D.DateTime) FROM sheet1 D WHERE D.userid=S.userid AND D.Customer=S.Customer AND D.Food=S.Food AND D.userid=S.userid AND D.DateTime<S.DateTime),'h:nn:ss') AS DifCalc, S.userid, S.Customer, S.Food, S.DateTime, S.Activity
FROM sheet1 AS S
ORDER BY S.userid, S.Customer, S.Food, S.DateTime, S.Activity;
```

My table:

```
+---------+----------+--------+------------------------+----------+
| userid  | Customer |  Food  |        DateTime        | Activity |
+---------+----------+--------+------------------------+----------+
| Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 1:19:08 AM  | Serve    |
| Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 1:19:12 AM  | Trash    |
| Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 6:20:11 AM  | Serve    |
| Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 6:20:11 AM  | Trash    |
| Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM   | Serve    |
| Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM   | Trash    |
| Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 2:32:59 AM   | Trash    |
| Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 7:09:14 AM   | Serve    |
| Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 7:09:22 AM   | Trash    |
| Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 6:33:44 PM  | Serve    |
| Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 6:33:44 PM  | Trash    |
| Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM | Serve    |
| Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM | Trash    |
| Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 10:25:00 PM | Trash    |
| Server2 | Cust4    | Fries  | 3/31/2014 10:48:49 PM  | Serve    |
| Server2 | Cust4    | Fries  | 3/31/2014 10:48:49 PM  | Trash    |
| Server2 | Cust4    | Fries  | 3/31/2014 10:48:48 PM  | Serve    |
+---------+----------+--------+------------------------+----------+
```

My partly working, partly bad results:

```
+---------+---------+----------+--------+------------------------+----------+
| DifCalc | userid  | Customer |  Food  |        DateTime        | Activity |
+---------+---------+----------+--------+------------------------+----------+
|         | Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 1:19:08 AM  | Serve    |
| 0:00:04 | Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 1:19:12 AM  | Trash    |
| 5:00:59 | Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 6:20:11 AM  | Serve    |
| 5:00:59 | Server1 | Cust1    | Burger | 12/20/2014 6:20:11 AM  | Trash    |
|         | Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM   | Serve    |
|         | Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM   | Trash    |
| 0:01:50 | Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 2:32:59 AM   | Trash    |
| 4:36:15 | Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 7:09:14 AM   | Serve    |
| 0:00:08 | Server1 | cust2    | Burger | 11/8/2014 7:09:22 AM   | Trash    |
|         | Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 6:33:44 PM  | Serve    |
|         | Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 6:33:44 PM  | Trash    |
| 3:50:29 | Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM | Serve    |
| 3:50:29 | Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM | Trash    |
| 0:00:47 | Server2 | Cust3    | Fries  | 12/20/2014 10:25:00 PM | Trash    |
|         | Server2 | Cust4    | Fries  | 3/31/2014 10:48:48 PM  | Serve    |
| 0:00:01 | Server2 | Cust4    | Fries  | 3/31/2014 10:48:49 PM  | Serve    |
| 0:00:01 | Server2 | Cust4    | Fries  | 3/31/2014 10:48:49 PM  | Trash    |
+---------+---------+----------+--------+------------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide the prior time and you can do the difference calc from here (I named the data table "sample"):

```
SELECT Sample.userid, Sample.Customer, Sample.Food, Sample.DateTime, Sample.Activity, IIf([sample].[activity]="Trash",(select max(DateTime) from sample S where (s.userid=sample.userid and s.customer=sample.customer and s.food=sample.food and s.datetime<=sample.datetime and s.activity="serve"))) AS [Prior]
FROM Sample
ORDER BY Sample.userid, Sample.Customer, Sample.Food, Sample.DateTime, Sample.Activity;
```

Result:

```
userid  Customer    Food    DateTime    Activity    Prior
Server1 Cust1   Burger  12/20/2014 1:19:08 AM   Serve   
Server1 Cust1   Burger  12/20/2014 1:19:12 AM   Trash   12/20/2014 1:19:08 AM
Server1 Cust1   Burger  12/20/2014 6:20:11 AM   Serve   
Server1 Cust1   Burger  12/20/2014 6:20:11 AM   Trash   12/20/2014 6:20:11 AM
Server1 cust2   Burger  11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM    Serve   
Server1 cust2   Burger  11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM    Trash   11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM
Server1 cust2   Burger  11/8/2014 2:32:59 AM    Trash   11/8/2014 2:31:09 AM
Server1 cust2   Burger  11/8/2014 7:09:14 AM    Serve   
Server1 cust2   Burger  11/8/2014 7:09:22 AM    Trash   11/8/2014 7:09:14 AM
Server2 Cust3   Fries   12/20/2014 6:33:44 PM   Serve   
Server2 Cust3   Fries   12/20/2014 6:33:44 PM   Trash   12/20/2014 6:33:44 PM
Server2 Cust3   Fries   12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM  Serve   
Server2 Cust3   Fries   12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM  Trash   12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM
Server2 Cust3   Fries   12/20/2014 10:25:00 PM  Trash   12/20/2014 10:24:13 PM
Server2 Cust4   Fries   3/31/2014 10:48:48 PM   Serve   
Server2 Cust4   Fries   3/31/2014 10:48:49 PM   Serve   
Server2 Cust4   Fries   3/31/2014 10:48:49 PM   Trash   3/31/2014 10:48:49 PM
```

Comment: I think the only change from your code is I used <= for the datetime selection instead of the < you used - for the cases where the serve time and trash time are the same. I also limited it to Trash records only - the calculation doesn't seem to mean anything for Serve records.